# Dart's Dio is not setting Content-Length header

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm trying to send an image to AWS S3 with a signed URL in a multipart form using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). My current code is like this:

```
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(params.signedUrl);
  final Dio dio = Dio();

  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": MultipartFile.fromBytes(params.fileBytes),
  });
  final response = await dio.put(
    uri.toString(),
    data: formData,
    queryParameters: uri.queryParameters,
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        "Content-Length": formData.length, // Content-Length is beeing passed here!
        "Host": uri.host,
      },
    ),
  );
```

As you can see, I'm passing `"Content-Length"` directly to the `headers` option on the request, because otherwise AWS will give me an error (as I tested using Postman). However, when I get the error (because there's something wrong in my request) and print the error, using Flutter's [`inspect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-developer/inspect.html) function, I can see that the request headers **don't** include the `"Content-Length"` property I defined before.

This error is almost certainly not a bug from AWS, because they demand the `"Content-Length"` property, and I'm not sending it to them, because of Dio's strange behavior. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in my request or if this is a bug on Dio. What could it be?